# Sibling communication, ref undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Lets say I have the following code:

```
<View>
    <ComponentA>
        <TouchableHighLight onPress={this.refs.componentB.foo.bind(this)}><Text>Hey</Text></TouchableHighLight>
    </ComponentA>
    <ComponentB ref='componentB'>
    ....
    </ComponentB>
</View>
```

-

```
class ComponentB extends React.Component = {
    foo() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The ref for componentB will be undefined when I try to use it in ComponentA. Im guessing it's because i ComponentA tries to use it before the ref is assigned.

Whats the best way to fix this?

I could have all the functions in the parent component, but it will end up being a huge file if I dont separate it filled with functions that IMO should be contained in the child components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `onPress`-handler in a function:

```
<TouchableHighLight onPress={() => this.refs.componentB.foo()}>
```

Comment: Refs are a very dangerous shortcut. They should be avoided. Always. It may work in this case (though I am not sure refs give you access to methods inside a component). But refs are a sure way to get you into maintenance hell down the road.

Comment: "Never access refs inside of any component's render method – or while any component's render method is even running anywhere in the call stack." from the React docs. Also, that may work but just because a real user is not quick enough to tap that button and trigger the timing issue.

Comment: @fabio.sussetto the ref isn't accessed from within a render method, it's accessed within an event-handler. However, I totally agree with wintvelt's comment: it's a pretty bad behaviour to make use of refs. My answer is indeed a solution to the given issue, but should not be a recommended pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem in having these shared functions in a parent component, using props to call them when something happens in one of the children. 
That's actually an encouraged React pattern, because you make your children components easier to test.
If you make ChildA aware of ChildB, you are coupling them instead of having the parent to just coordinate them.

See also this:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions

> If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. Placing the state there often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" – instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I did it this way first, but i ended up with a parent component that was so cluttered in smaller functions and onChange functions and i felt it was getting out of hand, and i wanted to split them up into the components. they still update the state of parent.

Comment: Without some code it's hard to try and help you with further options. If you needed a lot of onChange functions maybe it could be that your children components API was too broad and not simple enough. From my experience, if you design you components properly, not using refs make things easier, not more complicated. Then I guess it depends on your scenario. If you have a small example of the problems you had, I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: Id love to share so you could look at it. But its a little bit too much code to paste here. Lets use this example. I have a todolist component. It has two child components, categories, and todos. For editing i use modals, that requires opener functions to set the active todo. the modal itself has inputs that requires onchange functions to update the state of the activeedit. i need functions to handle removing of cats/todos. All this ends up being 20 functions that clutter the main component, instead of separating them down into the components. Also i need the parent to be incharge of state.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access any method in `<Component B>` from `<Component A>`. **This is by design**, done on purpose, and for your own good :)
Best to stick to react design principles, and not try to make a shortcut. You will definitely regret any shortcuts later on.

And BTW: A `ref` is a reference to the mounted component in the DOM, not to the react component. So I don't think you could get it to work anyway. Besides, I would always advise anybody not to use refs, ever (I learned that from a Netflix talk on react).

One way to fix:

- Put a `doFooInB` boolean in state inside your parent `<View>` component
- Pass this `doFooInB` to `<Component B>` as a prop.
- `<Component B>` reads the prop, and responds accordingly (with an internal function called from B's render)
- Define an `onPress` event inside parent `<View>` component and pass function as prop to component A.
- `onPress` simply needs to `setState({ doFooInB : true })` or something to trigger re-render, which will trigger the method in component B.

Yes, this is more code, but it really is better than creating some shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

It's not better idea to give ref to component since ref can be done on DOM objects. so, the better solution is to make function in parent component and pass that function as props to child component in onPress() handler of child component call that method as this.props.method which will automatically call the parent component method. In this way parent component method can be executed successfully.

```
<ComponentA>
  constructor(){
   this.method = this.methodA().bind(this);
   }

   methodA(){
   }

 <ComponentA method=this.methodA/>

 <ComponentB>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.props.method}}>
  </ComponentB>
```